# trying to parse a cell from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xlwt

I have a dataframe that is made up of some selected columns from an excel spreadsheet.

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('seedtestexcelbytask.xls') 
writer = ExcelWriter('DFExport.xls') 
df = xls_file.parse(usecols=[2, 3, 15])
```

This is a small example of the dataframe

```
2         3         15
True      2/2/18    Seed 2 2in Holon, 83/1/2
True      2/3/18    Seed 1 1in Holon, 83/5
True      2/5/18    Seed 2 1.5in Holon, 26/1/2, 21/2, RW/1/2, H/7
```

Column 15 has different values in it some separated by a space, some a comma, and some a slash, here is an example

```
Seed 2 1.5in Holon, 26/1/2, 21/2, RW/1/2, H/7
```

Basically I am trying to reformat `df` by reading a row, holding on to the date value in column 3, then parse through the cell on the row at column 15 and break that cell down further adding the date and some value to the next row

```
2/2/18    83     1
2/2/18    83     2
2/3/18    83     5
2/5/18    26     1
2/5/18    26     2
2/5/18    21     2
2/5/18    RW     1
2/5/18    RW     2
2/5/18     H     7
```

I have tried options with xlrd and xlwt but find I just keep adding nested for loops, but I don't think that is the most efficient way to do it or is it?  I found pandas `iterrows()` but i am having a tough time trying to figure out how to get the output I would like with that.  I don't think I need some code I can copy and paste, but being new to Python I am having a hard time implementing pandas correctly apparently.  Being new to Python any pointers would be grand!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({2:['2/2/18','2/3/18','2/5/18'],3:['Seed 2 2in Holon, 83/1/2','Seed 1 1in Holon, 83/5','Seed 2 1.5in Holon, 26/1/2, 21/2, RW/1/2, H/7']})
a= pd.concat([pd.Series(row[2],row[3].split(',')) for _, row in a.iterrows()]).reset_index()
a= a[a['index'].str.contains('/')].reset_index(drop = True)
y = pd.DataFrame(a['index'].str.split('/',1).tolist(),columns = ['first','rest'])
y[0] = a[0]
df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['first'],row['rest'].split('/')) for _, row in y.iterrows()]).reset_index()
df2 = pd.concat([pd.Series(row[0],row['rest'].split('/')) for _, row in y.iterrows()]).reset_index()
df1['date'] = df2[0]
print(df1)
```

Result:

```
  index    0    date
0     1   83  2/2/18
1     2   83  2/2/18
2     5   83  2/3/18
3     1   26  2/5/18
4     2   26  2/5/18
5     2   21  2/5/18
6     1   RW  2/5/18
7     2   RW  2/5/18
8     7    H  2/5/18
```